# My Windows 7 machine keeps rebooting randomly

Tags: windows-7, reboot

I realize this is a pretty general problem so please bear with me. I thought this had to do with my RAM so I removed all but one 4GB, ran MEM86 on it and it turned out fine. My computer still reboots randomly. I feel like it might be IO related but I don't know how to test it. My C: is SSD and I have hard drive's connected as well. All internal. EventLog only shows me that the computer unexpectedly shut down but no error code as to why it did so. Any tips on what tools there are to diagnose these things?

Comment: How's the heat level?  Also, have you recently installed any new drivers, hardware or software?

Comment: temp is fine. it manifests itself quite randomly. more often when the computer is idle than when it's not as well.

Comment: If it is a desktop, I would try another psu.

Comment: It is indeed. Yeah I'll give that a try. I'm getting really really sick of this issue.

Comment: I have found the following product helpful when trying to figure out what is crashing a win 7 machine. It reads the dump files for you. 
http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed
It should point you to a software/driver problem if it exists. If it is going into sleep/hibernate modes when it crashes might want to try turning those features off for testing.

Comment: damn, I was hoping that would show me something but no. crash dumps are enabled but none are written.

Comment: do 1 thing... start PC...go to BIOS and wait for some time. If it restarts, it clearly is hardware problem..
also try booting Linux live CD and use it for some time to rule out all the hardware/power problems.

Comment: @tumchaaditya excellent suggestion! I have never thought of that before

Comment: You can check your power adapter connection, unstable power supply may restart.

Comment: @tumchaaditya yeah nice idea. had it on for 6 hours last night in BIOS and it was fine. I'm gonna disconnect all drives except my primary SSD and check if that might solve it tonight.

Comment: When you say it reboots, does it give BSOD or does it just restart?
Also try a Linux live CD to be 100% sure on memory/HDD/Power.

Comment: @tumchaaditya it just restarts. alright will do.

Comment: @tumchaaditya it was fine on the CD all night as well. I'm gonna start disconnecting HDD's and see what happens.

Comment: well then i cannot think of anything other than windows...
try running sfc /scannow from command prompt.

Comment: @tumchaaditya I think you might be right. it has persisted over two separate windows installations on two different SSD's though so I don't really know what to think. I'll try that tonight, thanks.

Comment: @tumchaaditya the scan was clean. when I disconnected all but my SSD it no longer wanted to boot off it though so I said f' it and wiped it and installed Windows on it again (go off site backup!). Don't know if it fixed the problem but we will see.

Comment: The suggestions for boot up to the BIOS or to a live CD were very good ones, I think - at least for isolating the problem even if a solution was not yet found. Maybe consolidate that info in an Answer so that future searches are more likely to find that info?

Comment: Yeah I'd prefer if @tumchaaditya get's credit for such an answer. I have not had any problems since disconnecting the other hdd's and installing a fresh version of win7 btw so I guess that could be added as a last resort suggestion for this problem.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Because either you self-answer it or we might as well close it for being too localized, because its not helping anyone else

Comment: The tips in the comments can be helpful for debugging this but none of them helped me unfortunately. My problems went away with reinstalling Windows. It can probably be marked too localized as I can't really say what was wrong.

Comment: When did you last blow out the cpu fan / fins and maybe even add some new thermal paste?

Comment: This most likely was not a heat issue as wiping windows fixed it. Most likely something got corrupted and is no longer so. Thanks for your suggestion though.